# Thread 1: Signal Sigabrt error while creating a timer app

Tags: ios, swift

Recently I have created a timer app (very simple) and have been receiving the error Thread 1: Signal Sigabrt. The console message is

```
2015-08-04 15:27:09.053 Egg Timer[12332:2557133] *** Terminating app due to
uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason:
'[<Egg_Timer.ViewController      0x7fea60e150e0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]:
this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key start.'
```

the actual code is

```
import UIKit
```

class ViewController: UIViewController {

```
var timer = NSTimer()

var time = 0

func incrementTime() {
    time++
    timelabel.text = "\(time)"
}

@IBAction func play(sender: AnyObject) {
    timer = NSTimer.scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval(1, target: self, selector: Selector("incrementTime"), userInfo: nil, repeats: true)
}

@IBAction func pause(sender: AnyObject) {
    timer.invalidate()
}

@IBAction func restart(sender: AnyObject) {
    timer.invalidate()
    time = 0
    timelabel.text = "\(time)"
}

@IBOutlet weak var timelabel: UILabel!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()


}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}
```

}

Comment: Can you check your IBOutlets?

Comment: Thank you this helped me I must have had a no longer established outlet. So I reestablished them all and it now works thank you!

Comment: If you would like you could post it as an answer and I will confirm.

Comment: Thanks! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check all of your `IBOutlets`. They are the primary trigger for the `NSUnknownKeyException`exception.